# is the iOS Developer Enterprise Program available in all countries?

Tags: enterprise, ios-enterprise

More specifically I am trying to confirm whether the iOS Developer Enterprise Program is available to a large organization residing in Russia. Does anyone know ?

Also, is the iOS Developer Program Enterprise license agreement available somewhere for an evaluation by a legal team ?

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple customer support.

Comment: it's about iOS Developer Enterprise Program. off of what topic ?

Comment: I'm basing that statement on ["Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175701/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic-for-stack-over), and I believe the consensus there would extend to this.

Comment: well ok. my question is about the developer program and its properties, not about application stores. but you're entitled to your opinion of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS Enterprise Program is available anywhere where the dev program is available. So it should be in Russia too. You can try to apply here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/.

Comment: thanks. I understand that theoretically it should be available, but I need to know for sure before submitting a solution proposal to a large client (in Russia). Is it available to organizations in Greece ? Do you know ?

Comment: Yes it is. There is no online apple store to pay for the subscription, but they accept other payment methods too. Keeping in mind that it is available in Greece, I assume that it is available in russia too.But you can always call them. Find the appropriate phone number here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php